# Update object in react with condition statement

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, axios

I'm updating status if there is a condiotion of comment?.length, I wanna only update comment if there is a length of comment, everything works fine, but I have a question.
Can I do this condition easier? I mean without mapping 2 times.

```
 const changeStatus = (id, status,comment) => {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/changeStatus", {
        id: id,
        status: status,
        comment: comment,
      })
      .then((res) => {
          comment?.length
            ? setStatus(
                status.map((val) => {
                  return val.id == id
                    ? {
                        ...val,
                        status: status,
                        comment: comment
                      }
                    : val;
                })
              ) : setStatus(
                status.map((val) => {
                  return val.id == id
                    ? {
                        ...val,
                        status: status,
                      }
                    : val;
                })
              );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just map once and put the condition inside the object

```
.then((res) => {
  setStatus(status.map((val) => {
    if(val.id === id){
      return {
        ...val,
        status: status,
        comment: comment.length ? comment : null
      }
    }
    return val
  })
}
```

Comment: thank you, but instead of null, val.comment worked without clearing comment